# Lock Screen Problem in HTC ONE X

Tags: lock-screens

How can I recover my clock-style lock screen after it failed to return on my HTC One X? I let the phone's battery run out. Then I recharged and turned my phone on, but I can't see my clock-style lock screen.

My screen is also cracked, just to let you guys know. I also tried many times to fix it in the settings but it still doesn't work. Also none of the other lock screen options work.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to set the lock screen in `Settings > Lock screen > Screen security`.

Comment: On Android 4.0 `Settings` > `Security` > `Screen lock`

Comment: I have tried that multiple times but nothing helps

Answer (score 0):

Try 
setting - - > personalize - - > lock screen style

Comment: Tried that but nothing works